# Microsoft Jscript Angular is undefined

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, visual-studio

As I'm trying to put some angular in my .net mvc website, I encounter the following error at runtime

> 0x800a1391 - Erreur d'exécution Microsoft JScript: 'angular' est
>   indéfini.

Which means: Error at Microsoft Jscript runtime: 'angular' is undefined .

This occurs for the following code

```
var customersApp = angular.module('propositionApp', ['ngGrid']);
```

Some research on the internet advise to add the following code in the head tag (i use angular 1.2.23)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-resource.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

But this generates even more runtime errors because some part of the code returned by the url are Null.

Of course, I've added angular to my project with nugget package.

Where does this problem "angular" is not defined?

Comment: You need to include angularjs as well before resource, route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are not requiring the general angular library. Add

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

in the head of your document before your javascript files.